# Add A Block is not working on dashboard in moodle?

Tags: moodle

I am working on moodle version 3.5.10 and fordson theme version 3.5

I was trying to add a link on dashboard page so for that i added a html block on the dashboard from "add a block" section so i can put my link in that block so i put that link without title in my admin user it is showing there but then i check in my student user it is not showing that block on the dashboard so why is this happening Am i doing anything wrong? or i am using the wrong way to add a link on the dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the HTML block on the " Default dashboard page " to display the block on all users dashboard page.

Setup your block on the below location and use the button "Reset Dashboard for all users" to reset the changes on dashboard blocks for all users.

```
Site Administrator > Appearance > Default Dashboard page
```

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/5944805/prasanna-t it is working fine.